# Using clause with left joins in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have sql query that looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM survey_subjects WHERE id IN (
  SELECT ss.id FROM survey_subjects ss
    LEFT JOIN survey_instances si ON si.survey_subject_id = ss.id
    LEFT JOIN survey_packs sp ON si.survey_pack_id = sp.id
    LEFT JOIN school_packs scp ON sp.school_pack_id = scp.id
    LEFT JOIN survey_orders so ON scp.survey_order_id = so.id AND so.administration_id = <administration_id>
  WHERE ss.administration_id = <administration_id> AND si.id IS NULL
);
```

I was thinking how can I make this query more readable. I was thinking about using  USING clause from PostgreSQL but it will not work for left joins. Is there any way to make it more readable?

Comment: `using` will of course work for left joins. But: `using` is only applicable if the join columns have the same name in both tables - which is clearly not the case for your tables.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should simplify the logic to this:

```
DELETE FROM survey_subjects WHERE id IN (
  SELECT ss.id 
  FROM survey_subjects ss LEFT JOIN
       survey_instances si
       ON si.survey_subject_id = ss.id
  WHERE ss.administration_id = <administration_id> AND si.id IS NULL
);
```

The additional `join`s are not doing anything.  They are not filtering the data (because the joins are left joins).  They are not affecting either column in the `WHERE` clause, nor the column in the `SELECT`.